# Should Workflow Server Be Able To Return Query Data?

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation-4

So, I have a WCF Workflow server. This server is consumed by an ASP.NET application. I wanted to use this server as backend. The ASP.NET application needs to perform queries like `FindAllClients`, `GetClientbyId` and such.

Question is: What kind of service should process these requests? Should these queries be exposed as workflows? Should a workflow server even process client data queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a workflow a workflow involved in FindAllClients()? Sounds to me like something that is not very workflow like so I suspect the answer is no. And in that case what would be the point of using a WF4 service over a standard WCF service?